# Switch NO/NC Both Live

Tags: electrical

I've got a 240V [water flow switch](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/flow-sensors/0256562) connected to the hot water pipe driving the shower - it has 3 cables (COM, NO, NC). When I connect a permanent live to COM, both NO and NC are live. It doesn't make any difference whether the shower is on or not. I don't understand how is this possible.. is it most likely that it's a fault switch?

Comment: How are you determining that they are hot?

Comment: Use the ohmmeter.

Comment: Did you disconnect all wires from the NO and NC terminals before testing?

Comment: Is your load more than 16 amps?

Comment: @DoxyLover I was using a non-contact pen.

Comment: I only had the common connected to the mains and then tested whether the NO and NC wires were live with the non-contact pen

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your non-contact voltage tester is fooling you. Such devices are not perfect and everything inside the switch is probably so close together that the tester cannot really tell.

If you have a voltmeter, try testing with one lead connected to neutral and the other on NC and then on NO. (Note that with a high-impedance input volt meter such as most digital meters, you may het a phantom reading on the open contact though it should be much lover than mains voltage.)

You can also try temporarily wiring in a light socket and test with that.